# How to make background colour fade in when div is scrolled down

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am currently designing a little one page portfolio for myself that you can see so far [here](http://www.ojstanley.com/oliver/index.html). What I am trying to achieve is, when you scroll down the div the background fades in from being transparent to being the yellow colour that is now. Furthermore, I want it to fade from the yellow to the grey when you keep scrolling.

Basically exactly like [this website](http://www.ixistore.be) has done it.

I've been searching the web all day and after trying 10+ different tutorials, reading countless forums and crying to myself I have found nothing that works for me. I can handle html and css but don't have a clue when it comes to jquery so I don't know where to begin when writing my own code.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could give me nudge in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: What you have been try so far ?

Comment: Realize that once you reach a certain point, the background div of the site changes colour. What can you do to specify that if height >= x, background-div change colour?

Answer (score 0):

You can animate with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    $(document).scroll(function(){
    t = (100 - $(this).scrollTop())/100;
    if(t<0)t=0;
    $('.skyB').css({opacity: t})
  })
```

[**FIDDLE Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fP54Z/)

Hope it helps you

Comment: That almost worked but it only began to fade when i scrolled the browser window down. The browser window itself doesn't scroll, its a DIV containing the sites content that has an overflow that scrolls

Comment: use your element id `$('div')` instead of `$(document)`

Answer (score 0):

How about this, see [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MW8N3/) (explained below):

```
var height_colors = [
    [0, "#FFF"],
    [50, "#FFFF00"],
    [100, "#FF0000"],
    [150, "#FF00FF"],
    [200, "#00FF00"],
    [250, "#0000FF"],
    [300, "#00FFFF"],
    [350, "#123456"],
    [400, "#654321"],
    [450, "ABCDEF"],
    [500, "FEDCBA"]
];

var box = $("#lipsum");
box.on("scroll", function () {
    var scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    $.each(height_colors, function(key, value) {
        if(scrollPos < value[0] || key == height_colors.length - 1) {
            box.css("background", value[1]);
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Given a scrollable div `#lipsum`, and an Array of `[<height>, <color>]` values, when we scroll our element, we check it's `scrollTop()` value, and iterate over our array until we find a `height` value which is lower than the current `scrollTop()`.

Now, this could be transformed in a number of ways. For example, rather than calculate the position of a scrollable div, you could calculate the scroll position relative to the `document`, and then replace your `height_colors` array, to be an array of elements, and colors to iterate over. You'd do very much the same thing, but calculate the `offset` of the iterated elements until you've got an element with an `offset` greater than the current `scrollTop`.

Your new Array could look like:

```
var height_colors = [
    ["#elem-a", "#FFF"],
    ["#elem-b", "#555"],
    ...
]
```

It might be better in this case to keep a track of the last checked element so that you use the "one before last" once you realise you've gone too far. (not checked this code)

```
 // Assign a default color for scroll positions before your first element
var last_color = "#FFF";
$.each(height_colors, function(key, value) {
    var current = $(value[0]);
    if(scrollPos < current.offset().top) {
        $("body").css("background", last_color);
    }
    last_color = value[1];
});
```

The link you provided seems to do something similar, and as someone pointed out, you could use the jQuery UI variant of `.animate()` to fade between colours (though in my example with only 50 pixel stops, a 200ms animation was far too long).